# How to pronounch "sth" or "ths"?

Tags: pronunciation

I find pronouncing words containing "sth" e.g. cloths or "sth" e.g. aesthetic quite challenging. Any tips to make it easier?

Comment: Does your language have the "th" sound /θ/?

Comment: There's not really a trick. /s/ pronounced as usual, /θ/ pronounced as usual, and your tongue smoothly glides between them, maintaining turbulence. Native speakers can struggle with these, especially in challenging contexts like several in a row. Are there any words that have created legitimate communication barriers for you, or are you just interested in sounding more natural?

Comment: @the-baby-is-you - yes. My wife can find it annoying when people say 'sikth', but I tell her they aren't doing it on purpose.

Comment: Practice saying the chemical *phenolphthalein*. and the rotten word phthisis (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phthisis). If you can get your mouth around those, *cloths* (θs) and *clothes* (ðz) should be easy. ;-) Seriously, English speakers have trouble with *ps* at the beginning of a word (e.g., *Psyche*), though not at the end (e.g., *tops*), so don't feel bad, just practice.